# c++ strtok skips second token or consecutive delimiter

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to read CSV comma delimited file, content of file are

```
      one,,three
```

And code to read file is this…

```
      inFile.getline(line, 500);                            
      token1 = strtok(line, ",");
      token2 = strtok(NULL, ",");
      token3 = strtok(NULL, ",");

      if(token1 != NULL){
             cout << "token1 = " << token1 << "\n";      
      }else{ 
             cout << "token1 = null\n" ;
      }
      if(token2 != NULL){ 
             cout << "token2 = " << token2 << "\n";      
      }else{ 
             cout << "token2 = null\n" ;
      } 
      if(token3 != NULL){ 
             cout << "token3 = " << token3 << "\n";      
      }else{ 
             cout << "token3 = null\n";
      }
```

Output is this

```
token1 = one
token2 = three
token3 = null
```

Whereas my expectation are that output should be like this…

```
token1 = one
token2 = null
token3 = three
```

I did change if statements from

```
     if(token1 != NULL)
```

To

```
     if(token1)
```

But it as well doesn’t works.

After checking this example http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/, I have updated

```
   token2 = strtok(NULL, ",");
```

To

```
   token2 = strtok(NULL, ",,");
```

As well it does not works

Comment: That's the way `strtok` works. I have stumbled into this as well. If you want to treat empty tokens you must write your own tokenizing function.

Comment: **cplusplus.com is a notoriously bad resource, don't believe what you read there.** Search http://cppreference.com instead. Also, use `strchr()` for finding a character in a string.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: While that site may have some (rather undeserved) notoriety, the linked page looks accurate, and answers this question. "The function first scans from the starting location for the first character **not** contained in *delimiters*", implying that consecutive delimiters are treated as a single delimiter.

Comment: The empty string between separators is not a 'token', actually. BTW consider white-space separators (for which, I suppose, the `strtok()` was invented)...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once I did face this problem while reading CSV comma delimited file. But we can't use `strtok()` as our solution in such problems where the delimiter character appears consecutively. Because according to the standard

> The first call in  the  sequence  searches  the  string
>       pointed  to  by `s1` for  the  first  character  that is *not*
>       contained in the current separator string pointed to by  `s2`.
>       If  no  such character is found, then there are no tokens in
>       the string pointed to by `s1` and the `strtok` function  returns
>       a  null  pointer.   If  such a character is found, it is the
>       start of the first token.  C11 §7.24.5.8 3

So, for my case I defined another solution using `strpbrk()` function which will also be useful for you.

```
#include<iostream.h>

char *strtok_new(char * string, char const * delimiter){
   static char *source = NULL;
   char *p, *riturn = 0;
   if(string != NULL)         source = string;
   if(source == NULL)         return NULL;

   if((p = strpbrk (source, delimiter)) != NULL) {
      *p  = 0;
      riturn = source;
      source = ++p;
   }
return riturn;
}

int main(){
   char string[] = "one,,three,";
   char delimiter[] = ",";
   char * p    = strtok_new(string, delimiter);

   while(p){
            if(*p)  cout << p << endl;
            else    cout << "No data" << endl;                
            p = strtok_new(NULL, delimiter);
   }
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
one
No data
three
```

Hope this is your desired output.

Comment: _This answer does not handle the case where the final character is not the delimiter; one of the tokenized character runs will be lost._

Answer (score 8):

From the standard (C99, referenced from C++11 for compatibility features):

> The first call in the sequence searches the string pointed to by s1 for **the first character that is not contained in the current separator string** pointed to by s2.
>
> Each subsequent call, with a null pointer as the value of the first argument, starts searching from the saved pointer and behaves as described above.

That means that, when looking for the second token, it first skips over **all** characters that match any in the delimiter string. Hence, `,,`is treated as a single delimiter in your input string.

If you want a tokeniser to work differently to the way the standard one works, you'll have to look elsewhere unfortunately, such as the code below:

```
#include <string.h>

char *paxtok (char *str, char *seps) {
    static char *tpos, *tkn, *pos = NULL;
    static char savech;

    // Specific actions for first and subsequent calls.

    if (str != NULL) {
        // First call, set pointer.

        pos = str;
        savech = 'x';
    } else {
        // Subsequent calls, check we've done first.

        if (pos == NULL)
            return NULL;

        // Then put character back and advance.

        while (*pos != '\0')
            pos++;
        *pos++ = savech;
    }

    // Detect previous end of string.

    if (savech == '\0')
        return NULL;

    // Now we have pos pointing to first character.
    // Find first separator or nul.

    tpos = pos;
    while (*tpos != '\0') {
        tkn = strchr (seps, *tpos);
        if (tkn != NULL)
            break;
        tpos++;
    }

    savech = *tpos;
    *tpos = '\0';

    return pos;
}
```

That, combined with the following test program, should give you what you need::

```
#include <stdio.h>

int usage (char *reason) {
    fprintf (stderr, "ERROR: %s.\n", reason);
    fprintf (stderr, "Usage: testprog <string> <separator>\n");
    return 1;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3)
        return usage ("wrong number of parameters");

    printf ("Initial string is '%s'\n", argv[1]);

    char *token = paxtok (argv[1], argv[2]);
    while (token != NULL) {
        printf ("Token is '%s'\n", token);
        token = paxtok (NULL, argv[2]);
    }

    printf ("Final string is '%s'\n", argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

That gives a full program so that you can test it, such as with the command:

```
testprog ,_start,,middle_,end, _,
```

which will tokenise the first string using the two separators in the second, the underscore and comma. The output of that shows how it works and you can see it picking up empty tokens, including at the start and end:

```
Initial string is ',_start,,middle_,end,'
Token is ''
Token is ''
Token is 'start'
Token is ''
Token is 'middle'
Token is ''
Token is 'end'
Token is ''
Final string is ',_start,,middle_,end,'
```

Just keep in mind that, using statics, it suffers from the same limitation as `strtok` - you can't run two tokenising actions side by side. You *could* make a `paxtok_r` to mirror `strtok_r` but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Seeing this function implemented ... ***wow*** it becomes blatantly obvious that `strtok` is not re-entrant. It is actually scary to think two threads in unrelated software components might simultaneously do string manipulation with `strtok` and those `static` variables will cause both to fail. Why does anyone use the non-reentrant version in production software?! The whole thing seems like a really bad idea now. _Thank you for opening my eyes :)_

Comment: @Andon, it's still workable provided you can guarantee no threads (which was pretty much the case when `strtok` was originally invented), and that a tokenising operation will finish before another starts (such as if it's done in a single config-file-reading function.

Comment: If the delimiter is a string, it will return empty on every other call. Improve?

Comment: @alsaleem, it's unclear what you're referring to, can you elaborate?

Comment: I used the code to parse an http response, the delimiter is "\r\n". I get one line correct then an empty string on second call, then the second line.

Comment: @alsaleem, that makes sense now. The `paxtok` function (like `strtok`) is not for multi-character delimiters, it's for single-character delimiters, of which there may be more than one. So, it you tokenise `ab\r<nothing>\ncd` with `\r\n`, you'll get `ab`, `<nothing>` (the empty string between `\r` and `\n`), and `cd`. You *could* use `\n` and then strip off the `\r` that shows up at the end of each line, or you could revert to `strtok` which considers multiple consecutive separators as a single one (but you won't then properly handle `ab\r\n<blank line>\r\ncd` if you want that blank line).

Comment: @alsaleem: or you could ask *another* question with your more specific needs then sit back for a few minutes while the swarm responds :-)

Comment: thanks. the function is not that difficult. I made my own. Actually, your answer gave me the courage to do mine.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `strsep()` instead of `strtok()`, the former treats multiple delimiters as empty tokens and returns all of them.

Unlike `strtok()`, you don't have to call `strsep()` with a `NULL` first argument. You can call it like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
    
int main(void) {
    char string[] = "this,is,the,string,,,,you,want,to,parse";
    char *strPtr = string;
    char *token;

    while (token = strsep(&strPtr, ",")) {
        printf("Processing '%s'\n", token);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The following output is produced by that program:

```
Processing 'this'
Processing 'is'
Processing 'the'
Processing 'string'
Processing ''
Processing ''
Processing ''
Processing 'you'
Processing 'want'
Processing 'to'
Processing 'parse'
```

If that `while` condition makes you nervous or elicits a compiler warning, you can always check for `NULL` explicitly:

```c
while ((token = strsep(&strPtr, ",") != NULL))
```

Keep in mind that some old compiler libraries don't have `strsep()` and, technically, it's not a part of the ISO standard, but it should be available in most implementations.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/ says:

> To determine the beginning and the end of a token, the function first scans from the starting location for the first character **not** contained in *delimiters* (which becomes the *beginning of the token*). And then scans starting from this *beginning of the token* for the first character contained in *delimiters*, which becomes the *end of the token*. The scan also stops if the terminating *null character* is found.

So, as the function 'scans (...) for the first character **not** contained in *delimiters*', then it skips any sequence of delimiter characters. That makes impossible for it to detect an 'empty token' between consecutive delimiters. You will have to scan the input string char-by-char yourself.

Comment: CiaPans answer is correct.   Strtok is not suitable for parsing CSV type files as  adjecent delimiters are silently swollowed.  If you have to do C and C++ you will need to find a nice library, or roll your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is improved and re-entrant version:

```
char *strtok_new_r(char * string, char const * delimiter, char **saveptr) {

    char *ptr, *riturn = 0;

    if (string != NULL) {
        *saveptr = string;
    }

    if (*saveptr == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    if ((ptr = strpbrk(*saveptr, delimiter)) != NULL) {
        *ptr = 0;
        riturn = *saveptr;
        *saveptr = ++ptr;
    }

    if (!ptr) {
        if (*saveptr) {
            riturn = *saveptr;
            *saveptr = NULL;
        }
    }

    return riturn;
}
```