# Manually implement c string function with security enhancements

Tags: c++, security, buffer-overflow, crt

I'm trying to write a replacement for the `_tcstok_s` function that doesn't skip initial delimiters. (`_tcstok_s` is a variant of the strtok function that uses `TCHAR`s and includes security enhancements documented at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ef0s5kh.aspx). I'm doing this due to the annoying behavior of strtok that skips consecutive delimiters. I got the idea from 
[c++ strtok skips second token or consecutive delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522583/c-strtok-skips-second-token-or-consecutive-delimiter).

The thing I don't understand is how to implement the security enhancements that make `_tcstok_s` better than `_tcstok`. How to I make sure my re-implementation is as secure as `_tcstok_s`?

Although my code is C++, I am using C-style strings because I am implementing an MSI DLL.

This is what I have so far, but I don't know how to add the `_s` security enhancements.

```
TCHAR *GetNextToken(TCHAR *strToken, const TCHAR *szDelimit, TCHAR **pszContext)
{
   if (strToken == NULL)
   {
      if ((pszContext == NULL) || (*pszContext == NULL))
         return NULL;
      TCHAR *pToken = _tcspbrk(*pszContext, szDelimit);
      TCHAR *szResult = *pszContext;
      if (!pToken)
      {
         *pszContext = NULL;
      }
      else
      {
         *pToken++ = _T('\0');
         *pszContext = pToken;
      }
      return szResult;
   }
   else
   {
      TCHAR *pToken = _tcspbrk(strToken, szDelimit);
      if (!pToken)
      {
         *pszContext = NULL;
      }
      else
      {
         *pToken++ = _T('\0');
         *pszContext = pToken;
      }
      return strToken;
   }
}
```

Comment: C and C++ are different languages! Identical syntax/grammar does not imply identical semantics.

Comment: @Olaf That's why I clarified that I am writing C++ code using c-style strings.

Comment: But you should not have added the C tag. Also there is no code shown in the question.

Comment: @Olaf I added the C tag because the strings and functions I am using are following C conventions rather than C++ conventions, and require a familiarity with the C language to use properly.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN: Nah, if you're writing a C++ program, just tag C++ please.  Because answers specific to the C language will not be relevant. These facilities, though non-idiomatic, are _C++_ features as you're using them and strictly require a familiarity with the _C++_ (not C) language to use properly.